# How can I send long emails in Siebel server script?

Tags: email, siebel

**In short**: how can I send an email using Siebel's `Comm Outbound Email` buscomp, when the email body is longer than 40.960 characters? I can use the `Outbound Communications Manager` BS instead (or another one), but I need the activity record to be created too.

---

In Siebel 7.8 you can send emails in a few different ways:

1. Pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> opens the `Send Communications Applet`, where the <kbd>Send</kbd> button invokes the underlying BC `Comm Outbound Email` → `EmailSend` method: the email is sent and a new activity record is created (`S_EVT_ACT` and `S_EVT_MAIL` tables). There is no length limit for the email body.
2. From server script, you can use the [`Outbound Communications Manager` service method `SendMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/CommSrvAdm/CommSrvAdm_BusServ8.html#wp1042984). It doesn't have length limitations either, but **it doesn't create any record in Siebel BCs**, it just sends the message without leaving any trace.

```js
var psOut:PropertySet = TheApplication().NewPropertySet();
var psIn:PropertySet = TheApplication().NewPropertySet();
psIn.SetProperty("ProcessMode", "Remote");
psIn.SetProperty("Charset", "iso-8859-1");
psIn.SetProperty("CommProfile", from);
psIn.SetProperty("MsgToList", to);
psIn.SetProperty("MsgSubject", subject);
psIn.SetProperty("MsgHTMLBody", body);
var bs:Service = TheApplication().GetService("Outbound Communications Manager");
bs.InvokeMethod("SendMessage", psIn, psOut);
```

3. Or you can replicate the F9 behaviour by creating the BC record yourself and invoking the (undocumented?) `EmailSend` method. The problem is that you **can't set a `Display Email Body` value longer than 40.960** characters, otherwise you get a `SBL-DAT-00235` error.

```js
var bo:BusObject = TheApplication().GetBusObject("Service Request");
var bc:BusComp = bo.GetBusComp("Comm Outbound Email");
bc.NewRecord(NewAfter);
bc.SetFieldValue("Email Format", "HTML/Plain Text");
bc.SetFieldValue("Email Charset", "iso-8859-1");
bc.SetFieldValue("Email Sender Address", from);
bc.SetFieldValue("Email Sender Name", from);
bc.SetFieldValue("Email To Line", to);
bc.SetFieldValue("Description", subject);
bc.SetFieldValue("Display Email Body", body); // will fail if body.length > 40960
bc.WriteRecord();
bc.InvokeMethod("EmailSend");
```

Why am I restricted to 40.960 characters (*and where did that number come from?*) in the `Display Email Body`, while the F9 applet doesn't have that limitation? I know that field is special; for starters, [Siebel 7.8 doesn't support database columns above 16.383 characters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/ConfigApps/ConfigApps_TablesColumns21.html), yet this field max length is 1.024.000 (not 40.960...). For that, the [field user property `Text Length Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/ToolsDevRef/ToolsDevRef_UserProps173.html) is defined (without value). Also, it isn't mapped to any column: it's a calculated field, but without calculated expression; I guess the BC's `CSSBCOutMail` class manages it. But still, it should be the same whether I'm using it from scripting or from an applet. Why isn't it, should I change anything anywhere to enable it?

My requeriment is to **send long emails from a server script, but I need the activity record to be created too**. Is there any hidden parameter that I can set when calling `Outbound Communications Manager` → `SendMessage`, in order to create the activity record? Or any way to avoid the error if I do `bc.SetFieldValue("Display Email Body", aVeryLongEmailBody);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this document (1676136.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1676136.1) in the Oracle support web, which answers a similar question:

> Customer is using Outbound Communications Manager business service method SendMessage to send emails out from a workflow and want to keep an activity record or have a view where they can see the email that were sent out using this method.

The workaround they offer is the same we were using: to create the activity record using the `Comm Outbound Email` BC. But instead of doing it directly with a NewRecord and a bunch of SetFieldValues, they use the `Inbound E-mail Database Operations` business service:

```js
var psOut:PropertySet = TheApplication().NewPropertySet();
var psIn:PropertySet = TheApplication().NewPropertySet();
psIn.SetProperty("BusObj", "Mail Agent Activity");
psIn.SetProperty("BusComp", "Comm Outbound Email");
psIn.SetProperty("Field: Description", subject);
psIn.SetProperty("Field: Display Email Body", body);
psIn.SetProperty("Field: Email Sender Address", fromAddress);
psIn.SetProperty("Field: Email Sender Name", fromProfile);
psIn.SetProperty("Field: Email To Line", toAddress);

var bs:Service = TheApplication().GetService("Inbound E-mail Database Operations");
bs.InvokeMethod("InsertRecord", psIn, psOut);
var error = psOut.GetProperty("ErrorMessage"); // "" if everything went ok
var actId = psOut.GetProperty("ID");
```

Doing so avoids the weird 40960 characters limitation.

In case anybody needs it, apparently there is also a `UpdateRecord` method, [but it's hidden](http://www.siebelish.com/2011/07/hidden-methods-updaterecorddeleterecord.html) in the BS definition. The parameters are similar: `BusObj` and `BusComp`, `Id` (the row id of the record you want to update), and a `Field: Name Of The Field` for each field you want to change.